# Can't figure out why I can't retrieve a simple string with Xpath

Tags: javascript, xpath, phantomjs

I can't figure out why I can't retrieve a simple string with XPath with this very simple snippet

```js
var page = new WebPage();
page.open('http://free.fr', function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access network');
    } else {
        function getElementByXpath(path) {
          return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null).stringValue;
        }

        console.log( getElementByXpath("//title/text()") );
    }
    phantom.exit();
}
```

always return nothing.

What I missed to print the title value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhantomJS has two contexts. Only the DOM context (page context) has access to the DOM, but it is sandboxed. You get access to the DOM context through [`page.evaluate`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html). But remember that:

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the `evaluate` function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.
>
> **Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will *not* work!**

This means that you cannot pass any DOM node that you find to the outer context. Although, there is a `document` object outside of the DOM context, but it doesn't do anything. It's only a relict of the way PhantomJS is written on top of QtWebkit.

Here's an example fix:

```js
var page = new WebPage();
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg){
    console.log("remote: " + msg);
};
page.open('http://google.fr', function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access network');
    } else {
        page.evaluate(function(){
            function getElementByXpath(path) {
              return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
            }
    
            console.log( getElementByXpath("//head/title/text()").textContent );
        });
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```